What is the usual way to store an article page in a database?
I'm a learning developer in web technologies, particularly Angular, and I am currently working on the website of our computer science club.
We plan to post some articles, cheatsheets, etc., and we would like to store them in a database with the date, the authors, some tags, a representative image, etc., and most importantly, the content of the article. We would like to do it with a database because we found it to be a common and more practical way, which we agree with.
However, we struggle to find a convenient storage system for the content of the article.
I found this has been already talked in another post :
Using a database to store and get html pages for website
And this made us choose a template system, with different entry in the database that will be placed in different places/way.
But I have some complementary questions.
If I store text, how can I highlight some part of the text ? Like, making a part bold or italic ?
I read that markdown could be an option.
But it lack some personalisation. Imagine I want to add a cool React component in the middle of an article, but only this one. I can't store it in the database, since my template does not contain an entry for it, only placeholder for text.
Same for images ; if I say in my template that I have one image for the top of the article, every article will have it, because it's in my template. But what if I want more images in one article ? And not in the others ? There is no placeholder for them since it's not in my template.
I would like to ask for your opinion and your experience to know what the best solution is. We also did not find a database system for our Angular project, so if you have any propositions, we would gladly take them too since we are not familiar with them yet.
However, we have a way to host the website, a domain name, and the elders of the club proposed that we look at a solution called an "ORM".
Thank you for your help.


We would like to do it with a database because we found it to be a common and more practical way, which we agree with.

Well, I don't agree with this idea. When we can mannage a bried description like a typical shop, have sense use the dbs to store the "info", but when we have a laaarge article, I feel is more logic create an .html
Imagine your dbs return objects like, e.g.
  {
    title: 'page 1',
    tags: 'info|angular',
    source: 'page1.html',
  },

You can to have a service like
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  listArticles(tagSelected:string[])
  {
     return httpClient.get(your-url?tagSelected.Join('|')
  }

  readArticle(pageHtml: string) {
    return this.httpClient
      .get('assets/' + pageHtml, { responseType: 'text' })
      .pipe(
        map((res: string) => {
          const rx = /(?<=<body>)((.|\r|\n)*?)(?=<\/body>)/;
          const rxStyles = /(?<=<style>)((.|\r|\n)*?)(?=<\/style>)/;

          const styles = rxStyles.exec(res) || ['', ''];
          const text = rx.exec(res) || ['', ''];
          return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
            '<style>' + styles[1] + '</style>' + text[1]
          );
        })
      );
  }
}

You can use some like
<div>
  @for(tag of tags;track $index) {
  <label
    ><input
      type="checkbox"
      [(ngModel)]="tagsSelect[$index]"
      (ngModelChange)="filter()"
    />{{tag}}
  </label>
  }
</div>
@for(article of articlesFiltered|async;track $index) {
<div>
  {{article.title}}
  <a (click)="readArticle(article)">read now!</a>
</div>
}
<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>

where
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
  readArticle(article: any) {
    this.dataService
      .readArticle(article.source)
      .subscribe((res: any) => (this.data = res));
  }
  filter() {
    const tagSelected = this.tags.filter((x, i) => this.tagsSelect[i]);
    this.articlesFiltered = this.dataService.listArticles(tagSelected)
  }

In this way, you can to have a serie of "pages.html" in the way
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    ....
  </style>
</head>
<body>
     ...
</body>

This allow you to hav pure html pages to your entries of the blog. It's more easy to any create a page .html (you can see in any navigator, and use any editor) and the table of the dbs it's more efficience.
You can see a little example in this stackblitz
(in the stackblitz I "hardcode" the elements of the table using rxjs operator of and an array that I filter)
